# Accessing PHP file on intranet application w/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-io

I'm trying to run a function in a PHP file (`helpers.php`) and the file is in the `/includes/` folder.

If I put the `helpers.php` in the same directory as the `index.php` (`/html/`) file then the function gets called and runs - but if I keep it in the `/includes/` folder and then use url: `/../includes/helpers.php` it won't run and says file does not exist.

Here is the error I'm getting with the code below on my local machine:

```
http://webds:8000/includes/helpers.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my code - how would I adjust it to access the `/includes/helpers.php` properly?

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/../includes/helpers.php',
    data: {'func':'addSKU'},
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Here is the structure - this is on our network and the root is the html directory.

```
/html
  index.php
/includes
  helpers.php
  config.php
/views
 /templates
     header.php
     footer.php
 index.php
 addSKU.php
 quotes.php
```

Comment: Where is your app running from, which web address is the AJAX running on?

Comment: what is the path of your root website directory, and where is the includes function relative to that

Comment: depends on the structure of your filesystem, but why not update this line like so: `url: '/includes/helpers.php'`

Answer (score 0):

`/../includes/helpers.php` means 'the file 'helpers.php' in the folder 'includes', which is situated one directory up from the root.

Now that last part doesn't seem right. How can a directory exist one directory up from the (virtual) root of your website? Or: how could a browser reach that directory?